# Drawable resources and text color

Tags: android, styles

I am using `drawables` to nicely style my buttons, and that works fine, except for the text color in the button.

I have defined a `state_enabled="false"` item in a `selector` and using `setEnabled` gives me the right button styles, but I have to jump through quite some loops to get the text color different. This code for example doesn't work (it shows no, or black, text when disabled, and darkgray when enabled):

```
public void setButtonsEnabled(boolean enable) {
    btnAccept.setEnabled(enable);
    btnDecline.setEnabled(enable);


    int color = R.color.White;
    if (!enable) {
        color = R.color.DarkGray;
    }
    btnAccept.setTextColor(color);
    btnDecline.setTextColor(color);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution.

The key lies in also setting the TextColor to a `selector` in `res/colors`:

```
   android:textColor="@color/button_text"
   android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
```

For the background selector I used this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item  android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_buddy_enabled"></item>
<item  android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_buddy_disabled"></item>
<item  android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_buddy_clicked"></item>
</selector>
```

And the textColor selector is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item  android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/White"></item>
<item  android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/Gray"></item>
<item  android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/White"></item>
</selector>
```

Simply calling `setEnabled()` will make everything work fine.

Comment: FYI you can minimize the color selector since state_pressed doesn't matter, in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong value for the color.  R.color.White returns the resource ID of the value, not the value itself.  Try Color.WHITE, or getResources().getColor(R.color.White)

Comment: Even though you are right, the solution was in something else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out `ColorStateLists`? They are pretty awesome. So basically apply all those ideas of `Drawable` selectors to a set of colors.

Make a folder called **[Your Project]/res/colors/** and then put an xml file in there called, button_color.xml (or whatever).

**button_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
    <!-- Any Enabled button, gets White Text -->
    <item
        android:color="@color/White"
        android:state_enabled="true" />

    <!-- Buttons with any other state, get DarkGray Text -->
    <item
        android:color="@color/DarkGray"/>
</selector>
```

And then for your `TextView`, you can just do something like, `mTextView.setTextColor(R.color.button_color);` At that point there is no need for that if/else type of logic, the `selector` will do it for you. The selector gets rolled up into the color resource but the class it actually generates is called a `ColorStateList` in case you find it referenced in other documentation.

Comment: Thanks. As you see, I also found it myself (as always just after I post my problem here ;-)).

Comment: It's giving warning "URI is not registered" in Android studio ?..u know why?

Comment: also it say Error:Execution failed for task '.
> Unsupported node 'item' in file /app/src/main/res/colors/color_white_selector.xml .. nay suggestion?